# Angular routing: How do I target sub-route in another module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have the main module say, *app-routing.module* as follows:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'sport',
    loadChildren: './sport/sport.module#SportModule',
    data: { game: GAME.SPORT }
  }
  {
    path: 'horse-racing',
    loadChildren: './sport/sport.module#SportModule'
    data: { game: GAME.HORSE_RACING }
  }
]
```

Then in sport-module I have:

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'horse-racing',
    component: RacingComponent
  }
  {
    path: '',
    component: SportComponent
  }
]
```

I basically want that when user goes to:

1. */sport* to map to the following route in sport module:

```
    {
       path: '',
       component: SportComponent
    }
```

2. */horse-racing* to map to the following route in sport module:

```
    {
       path: 'horse-racing',
       component: RacingComponent
    }
```

Question: How do I configure *app-routing.module* to load the horse-racing route directly?

Answer (score 0):

please try adding like this

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'horse-racing',
    component: RacingComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sport',
    component: SportComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/horse-racing',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  }
]
```

therefore by default when there is emply string after `localhost:4200` it will redirect to `localhost:4200/horse-racing`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I want sport (not horse-racing) to be the default route is sport module. I basically want 'horse-racing' route defined in app-routing module to map to the  'horse-racing' route in sport module

Answer (score 0):

The child route always adds something to the parent route. That means that if you want to group `SportComponent` and `HorseRacingComponent` in the `SportModule` **and** have the child routes defined as `/sport` and `/horse-racing` (eg. localhost:4200/horse-racing) the root route must be an empty route.

**Solution**

So, the root route in the `AppRoutingModule` would be:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './sports/sport.module#SportModule' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

and the child route in `SportingRouteModule`:

```
const sportRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    children: [
      { path: 'sport', component: SportComponent },
      { path: 'horse-racing', component: HorseRacingComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

Check this Stackblitz to see it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yh5xep

**Alternative**

On the other hand you could have the child routes configured as `/sport` and `/sport/horse-racing` where '/sport' is the default child route for the `SportComponent`. In that case the root routes could be configured like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'sport', loadChildren: './sports/sport.module#SportModule' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

And the child route in `SportRoutingModule`:

```
const sportRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: SportComponent },
      { path: 'horse-racing', component: HorseRacingComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

The demo of the alternate solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rh8drh